# load data into file upload MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

Html code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "RoomInfo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
     <input type="file" class="multi" />
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
     </p>
}
```

Controller code;

```
public ActionResult Search(string id)
        {
            var arrayid = id.Split(',');
            int roomid = int.Parse(arrayid[0]);
           ViewBag.ImageID = new SelectList(db.RoomImgs.Where(p => p.RoomID == roomid), "ImageID", "FilePath");
            return View(roominformation);
        }
```

I'm trying to upload the image into server and insert the file path into database and I successful to insert in to server and database, but now I need to select out the file path and put into the file upload tag in Edit mode. I trying some method but still fail to set in. How can I do it?

Comment: Is there a [Post] HTTP verb for the `Edit` ActionResult?

Comment: sorry for unclear info, the Controller code is for search image, I'm just want select the data and put in the file upload..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is display the previously uploaded image and then allow users to modify the image.

You can't populate the file input like you would a text box. What most websites do is display the image above the input and then have the input box below if you want to change the image. If you want to remove the image then you could also have a checkbox for removing the image. Then on the server side you have to check if the checkbox is checked and clear the image or, if the file input is populated store the new image and update the database.